# Can I Implement Caching in MVC, If so how?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Can I Implement Caching in MVC, If so how? I wanted to implement Cache in Controllers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way to do that in controller is

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
  {
     return View();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Amitab, your solution is helpful ..But my doubt is Can I implement Application level cache in ASP.Net MVC..If so How? and I need to implement for the Objects data inside Index method not for Index method

Answer (score 1):

You can use the asp.net caching mechanisms - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28VS.9%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be implementing caching, you will most likely want to use something more advanced than simple output caching. Usually it is best to simply cache the data that you're using to load the view.

You want to make it so that your controllers get cached data when they try to get the data they need for the view.

If you know and use repositories to get your data, you can implement a CachedRepository, which will make it so that when you access your data, you will get the cached version if it's been retrieved once already.

This is a great post by Steve Smith on the [CachedRepository Pattern](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern/).